# POSTed values will never be null?

Tags: php, forms, validation, isnull

I am required for an assignment to check if certain html form fields (type="text") assigned to variables are null. I'm finding that is_null() is not detecting variables to which empty fields are assigned, but empty() does.

What is the reason why POSTed values are not null? Also, would isset() be a better choice for this?

Comment: Are you talking about a field that is in the page but doesn't have any content, or a field which isn't in the page? i.e. if it was GET would the URI be `?foo=` or `?`?

Comment: Just to explain: A submitted form field won't ever be `null`. At least the field has been submitted even it was empty.

Comment: Sorry - to clarify, I mean a field which is present on the page but the user has left blank when they submitted.

Answer (score 0):

If an input field is not set on your web page, the browser will not send it at all. Therefore you are not seeing null, you are not seeing anything arrive.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work for you. If there is form element that matches your array key, it will be set to an empty string, if the form element doesn't exist isset will return false.

```
if(!isset($_POST['name']))
```

Answer (score 0):

Because an empty value is semantically more sensible from a data point of view than a null, which is more of a runtime, programming concept. A null value actually cannot be marshalled across the wire in a platform and programming language agnostic fashion.